# How to get info from google sheets based on drop list selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

In my webapp show a drop list that get the sheets name from a google sheets file so I'm trying to get the sheet info based on the selected sheet from the drop list . 
the code works but not based on the selection of droplist.
what I did wrong ? 
here is the full sample hopefully it will help to identify the issue

CODE.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dup');
}

function getSheetNames() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  var sObj={sA:[]};
  shts.forEach(function(sh){
    sObj.sA.push(sh.getName());
  })
  return sObj;
}


function getDataFromServer(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data =ss.getSheetByName(e.name).getRange("B2:J22").getValues();
  var ar = data.splice(0,1); //add headers
  data.forEach(function(f) {
    if (~f.indexOf(e.searchtext)) ar.push(f);
   });
   e['sA']=getSheetNames().sA;
 return ar;
}
```

dup.HTML

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">

     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
     <select id="sel1"></select><label for="sel1">Report Date </label>
    </body>   
      <script>

       $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        sObj.sA.unshift('Please Select a report date');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<sObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(sObj.sA[i],sObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getSheetNames();
    });

   const loaded = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        google.charts.load('current');
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(res);
      });
      let wrapper = null;

      async function drawTable(arr) {
        await loaded; //wait if charts is not loaded
        wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'Table',
          dataTable: arr,
          containerId: 'table_div',
        });
        wrapper.draw();
      }

      function getData(f) {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(drawTable,function(rObj){
        $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        rObj.sA.unshift('Please Select by Report Date');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<rObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(rObj.sA[i],rObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
         .getDataFromServer(f);
      }


    </script>

    <body>
    <form>

      <input  type="button"id="display"class="btn btn-primary" value="retrieve report Data" onClick="getData(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>


  <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's your html a little better organized.  I haven't checked all of the functions but atleast the select tag is inside your form and there's just a simple html structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      <script>
       $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        sObj.sA.unshift('Please Select a report date');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<sObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(sObj.sA[i],sObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getSheetNames();
    });
       const loaded = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        google.charts.load('current');
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(res);
      });
      let wrapper = null;

      async function drawTable(arr) {
        await loaded; //wait if charts is not loaded
        wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'Table',
          dataTable: arr,
          containerId: 'table_div',
        });
        wrapper.draw();
      }

      function getData(f) {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(drawTable,function(rObj){
        $('#sel1').css('background-color','#ffffff');
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        rObj.sA.unshift('Please Select by Report Date');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<rObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(rObj.sA[i],rObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
         .getDataFromServer(f);
      }
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <form>
     <select id="sel1"></select><label for="sel1">Report Date </label>
      <input  type="button"id="display"class="btn btn-primary" value="retrieve report Data" onClick="getData(this.parentNode)" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where can I see the droplist in your script?

Comment: I have it in HTML $(function(){
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(sObj){
        var select=document.getElementById('sel1');      
        sObj.sA.unshift('Please Select a report date');
        select.options.length=0;
        for(var i=0;i<sObj.sA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i]=new Option(sObj.sA[i],sObj.sA[i]);
        }
      })
      .getSheetNames();

    });

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you provide the script for replicating your issue?

Comment: its not allowing to paste all the code , here is a link for the webapp   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwxBPpXJlAjdnX2EOZ0oQyQ6tDOm3yrLngqp8OaRRai/dev      so basically I want when I pick the report date and press on " retrieve button " to show the info in that report

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the information. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your issue from your question and your provided information. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike , I'm very new to this , sorry I couldn't explain better.

Comment: For example, how about sharing the Spreadsheet including the script? If you can do, of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I couldn't use this google spreadsheet from mobile ( scripts didn't run ) so I decided to convert it to webapp

Comment: Thank you for providing it. Can you explain about your GAS project? Because there are many functions with the same function names in your GAS project. In this case, the script might not work as you expect. At first, it is required to remove this issue.

Comment: Did you try to deploy it as webapp ?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot do it. Because there are many functions with the same function names in your GAS project. In this case, the script might not work as you expect, even when the script is run and modified. At first, it is required to remove this issue. Or can you provide a simple sample script for replicating your issue of `not based on the selection of droplist`?

Comment: I will create a completely new sheet with only the issue i want to solve , maybe this will help , sorry im very beginner in this. I appreciate you taking tom to look into it

Comment: Thank you for replying and cooperating. When the information for replicating the issue is provided, it will help users including me think of the solution.

Comment: I revised my code Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. I noticed that your issue had already been resolved just now. I'm glad for it.

Comment: I was hoping to know what was wrong with my code ,

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your current situation? Because I cannot understand about your situation. Wasn't your issue still resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've done it.  This script starts off by getting a list of all spreadsheets in your account and it populates a drop down on the webapp.  You then select the spreadsheet and it goes back to the server to get all of the sheets for the selected spreadsheet. Once you make your selection it then loads that entire sheet on the web app and provides the capability for you to edit the data on that sheet.

Code.gs:

```
function htmlSpreadsheet(ssO) {
  var br='<br />';
  var s='';
  var hdrRows=1;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssO.id);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(ssO.name);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  s+='<table>';
  for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    s+='<tr>';
    for(var j=0;j<rngA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(i<hdrRows)
      {
        s+='<th id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="20" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      } 
      else
      {
        s+='<td id="cell' + i + j + '">' + '<input id="txt' + i + j + '" type="text" value="' + rngA[i][j] + '" size="20" onChange="updateSS(' + i + ',' + j + ');" />' + '</th>';
      }
    }
    s+='</tr>';
  }
  s+='</table>';
  s+='</body></html>';
  var namehl=Utilities.formatString('<h1>%s</h1>', ss.getName());
  var shnamehl=Utilities.formatString('<h2>%s</h2>', sht.getName());
  var opO={hl:s,name:namehl,shname:shnamehl};
  return opO;
}

function updateSpreadsheet(updObj) {
  var i=updObj.rowIndex;
  var j=updObj.colIndex;
  var value=updObj.value;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(updObj.id);
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName(updObj.name);
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  rngA[i][j]=value;
  rng.setValues(rngA);
  var data = {'message':'Cell[' + Number(i + 1) + '][' + Number(j + 1) + '] Has been updated', 'ridx': i, 'cidx': j};
  return data;
}

function doGet() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlss').setWidth(1000).setHeight(450);
  return userInterface.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function getAllSpreadSheets() {
  var files=DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); 
  var s = '';
  var vA=[['Select Spreadsheet',0]];
  while(files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName=file.getName();
    var fileId=file.getId();
    vA.push([fileName,fileId]);
  }
  //return vA;
  return {array:vA,type:'sel1'};
}

//working on this function right now 2017/11/08
function getAllSheets(ssO) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssO.id);
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var vA=[['Select Sheet']];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var name=allSheets[i].getName();
    vA.push([name]);
  }
  return {array:vA,type:'sel2'};
}
```

htmlss.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#msg').html('Please wait. Collecting a list of all Spreadsheets...');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
         .getAllSpreadSheets();
    });

    function updateSS(i,j)
    {
      var str='#txt' + String(i) + String(j);
      var value=$(str).val();
      var ssId=$('#sel1').val();
      var name=$('#sel2').val();
      var updObj={rowIndex:i,colIndex:j,value:value,id:ssId,name:name};
      $(str).css('background-color','#ffff00');
      google.script.run
         .withSuccessHandler(updateSheet)
         .updateSpreadsheet(updObj);
    }

    function updateSheet(data)
    {
      //$('#success').text(data.message);
      $('#txt' + data.ridx + data.cidx).css('background-color','#ffffff');
    }

    function updateSelect(dtO)
    {
      $('#sel1').css('background','#ffffff');
      $('#sel2').css('background','#ffffff');
      $('#msg').html('Spreadsheet List has been updated.  Now select a SpreadSheet to display');
      var select = document.getElementById(dtO.type);
      var vA=dtO.array;
      select.options.length = 0; 
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
      {
        select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i][0],vA[i][vA[i].length-1]);
      }
    }

    function loadSelectSheet()
    {
       var shId=$('#sel1').val();
       var name=$('#sel1').text();
       $('#sel1').css('background','#ffff00');
       document.getElementById('ssname').innerHTML="";
       var ssO={name:name ,id:shId}
       google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(updateSelect)
           .getAllSheets(ssO);

    }

    function displaySelectedSheet()
    {
       var ssId=$('#sel1').val();
       var name=$('#sel2').val();
       $('#sel2').css('background','#ffff00');
       document.getElementById('shname').innerHTML="";
       var ssO={id:ssId,name:name};
       google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(displaySheet)
           .htmlSpreadsheet(ssO);
    }

    function displaySheet(opO)
    {
        $('#sel2').css('background','#ffffff');
        document.getElementById('ssname').innerHTML=opO.name;
        document.getElementById('shname').innerHTML=opO.shname;
        document.getElementById('sss').innerHTML=opO.hl;
    }

    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      th{text-align:left}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="msg"></div><br />
  <br /><select id="sel1" onChange="loadSelectSheet();"></select>
  <br /><select id="sel2" onChange="displaySelectedSheet();"></select>
  <div id="ssname"></div>
  <div id="shname"></div>
  <div id="sss"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I did this several years ago but I still use it occasionally.

Comment: once again you saved me with a perfect code ! . Thanks Cooper

Comment: Cooper even that your codes works , do you mind check why my code is not working ?

Comment: There is nothing in your form.  Try putting all of your html together in one place with the basic html structure. `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><script></script></head><body><form</form></body></html>` Right now you have multiple body tags and your html is messy and disorganized.

Comment: Do you think the reason for the code is not working is the wrong structure?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't even use a form in this case. But if you want to then your going to have to put the `<select>` inside of the form.

Comment: I added a better organized version of your html to your question.  I hope you don't mind.  You may still need to debug it some more.

Comment: I don't think `e.name` is the value of the selected sheet name.  The select tag doesn't even have a name attribute.  But I would have got it with `$('#sel1').val()` and not even used the form at all.  I would just have used the select's onChange event to get the sheet  data.

Comment: I tried adding $('#sel1').val() before at the end but it didnt work ,         .getDataFromServer(f+$('#sel1').val());

Comment: Well you can’t really take a piecemeal approach here. You have to decide what you wanna do and then do it consistently all the way through your code.  But I don’t think e.name in your server code is the name of the sheet.

Comment: Will try to follow e.name lead .Thanks Cooper